# How to send a HTTP Post Request in Delphi 2010 using WinInet

Tags: delphi, http, post, wininet

I want to send a HTTP Post Request in Delphi 2010 using WinInet, but my script doesn't work ;/

It's my Delphi script:

```
uses WinInet;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hNet,hURL,hRequest: HINTERNET;
begin
  hNet := InternetOpen(PChar('User Agent'),INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG or INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if Assigned(hNet) then
  begin
  try
    hURL := InternetConnect(hNet,PChar('http://localhost/delphitest.php'),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,nil,nil,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,DWORD(0));
    if(hURL<>nil) then
      hRequest := HttpOpenRequest(hURL, 'POST', PChar('test=test'),'HTTP/1.0',PChar(''), nil, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD or INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE,0);
    if(hRequest<>nil) then
      HttpSendRequest(hRequest, nil, 0, nil, 0);
    InternetCloseHandle(hNet);
  except
      ShowMessage('error');
    end
  end;
end;
```

and my PHP script:

```
$data = $_POST['test'];
$file = "test.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "a");
flock($fp, 2);
fwrite($fp, $data);
flock($fp, 3);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting all lines with 4 spaces. Then syntax-highlighting will be applied.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to do it yourself. You are allowed to edit the question as well.

Comment: oh, my error, but without this it still not work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Major problems:**

- The second parameter of `InternetConnect` should contain only the name of the server, not the entire URL of the server-side script.
- The third parameter of `HttpOpenRequest` should be the file name (URL) of the script, not the POST data!
- The actual POST data should be the forth parameter of `HttpSendRequest`.

**Minor problems**

- `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG or INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG`: It is sufficient with `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG`.
- `DWORD(0)` is overkill. `0` is enough.

**Sample Code**

I use the following code to POST data:

```
procedure WebPostData(const UserAgent: string; const Server: string; const Resource: string; const Data: AnsiString); overload;
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  hHTTP: HINTERNET;
  hReq: HINTERNET;
const
  accept: packed array[0..1] of LPWSTR = (PChar('*/*'), nil);
  header: string = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
begin
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    hHTTP := InternetConnect(hInet, PChar(Server), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    try
      hReq := HttpOpenRequest(hHTTP, PChar('POST'), PChar(Resource), nil, nil, @accept, 0, 1);
      try
        if not HttpSendRequest(hReq, PChar(header), length(header), PChar(Data), length(Data)) then
          raise Exception.Create('HttpOpenRequest failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hReq);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hHTTP);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

For instance:

```
WebPostData('My UserAgent', 'www.rejbrand.se', 'mydir/myscript.asp', 'value=5');
```

**Update in response to answer by OP**

To read data from the Internet, use `InternetReadFile` function. I use the following code to read a small (one-line) text file from the Internet:

```
function WebGetData(const UserAgent: string; const Server: string; const Resource: string): string;
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  hURL: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  i, BufferLen: cardinal;
begin
  result := '';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar('http://' + Server + Resource), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    try
      repeat
        InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen);
        if BufferLen = SizeOf(Buffer) then
          result := result + AnsiString(Buffer)
        else if BufferLen > 0 then
          for i := 0 to BufferLen - 1 do
            result := result + Buffer[i];
      until BufferLen = 0;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

Sample usage:

```
WebGetData('My UserAgent', 'www.rejbrand.se', '/MyDir/update/ver.txt')
```

This function thus only reads data, with no prior POST. However, the `InternetReadFile` function can also be used with a handle created by `HttpOpenRequest`, so it will work in your case also. You do know that *the* WinInet reference is MSDN, right? All Windows API functions are described in detail there, for instance [InternetReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385103(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I have merge these scripts and the script now looks like this:
http://paste.org/pastebin/view/19370

Works as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @noxwow "Check" doesn't seem like a great name for a method.

Comment: Im using turbo delphi and it says: [Pascal Fehler] uHTTP.pas(22): E2010 incompatible types: 'Char' und 'WideChar'.. How to fixx?

Comment: In WebPostData, why you use AnsiString instead of String for the type of parameter Data? String is WideString.

Comment: Also why you use AnsiChar for Buffer, does that means the response text will be in ANSI, not Unicode?

Comment: @alancc: Before Delphi 2009, `string` was `AnsiString`; since Delphi 2009, `string` is `UnicodeString`. `WideString` is something else. But more to the point: this code reads only bytes from the WWW. It isn't aware of character encodings. Changing the string to `string` (=`UnicodeString`)  would almost certainly make the code fail, because the WWW file is probably either ASCII or UTF-8 (so English letters are 1 byte wide), while `string` is two bytes per char, so the output would be garbage (mostly random Chinese characters). Using `AnsiString`, this will work correctly for WWW ASCII files.

Comment: But you are right: this doesn't support non-ASCII characters. It only supports ASCII. To make it work with non-ASCII, you need to add more code to (1) determine the actual encoding of the WWW file and then (2) convert the bytes obtained from the WWW to a UTF-16LE `string`.

Comment: (My response above is for reading, but roughly the same remarks apply to writing. If you want to write UTF-8 data, you need to convert the UTF-16LE `string` into UTF-8 explicitly. Remember that using WinInet is low level and that this A was written almost at the same time as Delphi became Unicode!)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, Thank you very much. I create a function in Delhi XE3 based on yours. And now have made sure both the data sent and received are all in AnsiString or AnsiChar.

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  BufferIn : INTERNET_BUFFERS;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of Byte;
  FTmp: TSomeStream:
  FURL: string;
  ...
begin
... // Create FTmp, set FUrl, ...

  NetHandle := InternetOpen( 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3',
                          INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);

  UrlHandle := HttpOpenRequest(NetHandle, 'POST', PChar(FURL), nil, nil, nil, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);

  ... // Check handles, etc
  try
    BufferIn.dwBufferTotal := FTmp.Size;

    if not HttpSendRequestEx(UrlHandle, @BufferIn, nil, 0, 0) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Error on HttpSendRequestEx %d\n', [GetLastError()]);

    size := FTmp.Read(Buffer, 1024);
    InternetWriteFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, size, BytesWritten);

    while (BytesWritten = size) and (BytesWritten > 0) do
    begin
      size := FTmp.Read(Buffer, 1024);
      InternetWriteFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, size, BytesWritten);
    end;
  finally
    FTmp.Free;

    InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end;
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you use the Firefox UserAgent?

Comment: No. Just a leftover from issue I had once trying to download html page where I got message to "use a real browser" instead of html I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library (called 'HTTPGet component for Delphi 32') on http://www.utilmind.com. It installs a visual control into your component palette.
It does exactly what you want, so you may want to take a look.