# How to simulate a browser with Delphi

Tags: delphi, browser, bots

I need build an application to get stock exchange data on web. For this, i need get page code and sometimes send requests (post and get). I'm trying to make something like a bot.
Could somebody help me please?

Comment: There are several examples of how to do this (using Delphi and the WinInet part of the Windows API) at SO already.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't find it, could you please send me the link? Is possible delete my question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977720/how-to-send-a-http-post-request-in-delphi-2010-using-wininet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823542/how-to-send-a-http-post-request-in-delphi-using-wininet-api

Answer (score 6):

Delphi ships with [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org), which has `TIdHTTP` and `TIdCookieManager` components for handling HTTP requests and replies.